# Hibernate domain model

Tags: java, hibernate

When specifying one to many relationships in the domain model....is it better to initialize the set?

i.e.

```
private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<Book>();
```

OR

```
private Set<Book> books;
```

Thxs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initializing it in the first place prevents you from null checks all over the place, so my advice would be the first.

Comment: is there any disadvantage in initialising?

Comment: The cost of a Set which might not be used. Buts it should be worth the price.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter from hibernate perspective. It basically question of basic java practice.